# how to define a type to check that an object contains an id key?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define an interface so that it can contain any number of keys but must contain the `id` key?

```
interface HasId{
   id: number
}
```

Something like this can be defined but it will output an error if there is another key in the data structure.

Comment: What is your `data structure`? In principle, you can define an interface like the one you have, and then use it with an object like `const obj = { id: 10, otherProp: 'Value' }`, e.g. passing it into a function with a `input: HasId` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in fact you need to create a **dictionary** type. More info on [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
interface HasId {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

*You can also make it more generic like*

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

interface HasId extends IDictionary<number> {
    id: number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an intersection type with your original type and a standard Object for example :

```js
interface HasId {
    id: number;
}

type AtLeastHasId = HasId & {[key: string]: number};

const test1: AtLeastHasId = { // Property "id" is missing
};

const test2: AtLeastHasId = { // Fine
    id: 123
};

const test3: AtLeastHasId = { // Fine
    id: 123,
    other: 456
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4EkAmyDeAUMicsDgFzIgCuAtgEbQDchAvoYWAJ4AOKAQTAAZCJjDpseALxpMuZADICAbQDWEblQxgooAOYBdKrUbQ2rQggD2IHckg6AjFSGjxkhbPzIA9L+QABShrfigeZAAickiyDGQ6YAwMA3ZLGzswBwgdACZXETEdTxkCPwCAMVAIYlJyKidcgGY0zgz7RzAmgvdi+VKff2QqkBrSMkpkRqaAGlqSazAAC2gqABYAVgA2NKA)